# GraphQL - Union Types giving the error no class could be found for that type name

Tags: graphql, graphql-schema

In my GraphQL schema file I'm trying to add a union type like so:

```
type CoOverrides {
    coId: String
    type: String
}

type SoOverrides {
    soId: String
    freeInterval: String
}

union CoOrSoOverrides = CoOverrides | SoOverrides
```

I then assign this to my type like so:

```
type Campaign {
    id: ID!
    title: String
    overrides: [CoOrSoOverrides]
}
```

However on starting the graphql server I keep getting the error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaParser]: Factory method 'schemaParser' threw exception; 
nested exception is com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.SchemaClassScannerError: 
Object type 'CoOverrides' is a member of a known union, but no class could be found for that type name.  Please pass a class for type 'CoOverrides' in the parser's dictionary.
```

What exactly is this and how do I add this class into the parser's dictionary?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As in error message - pass `CoOverrides` class to dictionary.

```
@Configuration
public class SchemaParserConfig {

    @Bean
    public SchemaParserDictionary schemaParserDictionary() {
        return new SchemaParserDictionary()
                .add(CoOverrides.class);
    }

}
```